# HTML Encoding Issue During MySQL Backup in MySQL Administrator Tool

Tags: mysql, mysql-backup, mysqladministrator

- I have table **ABC **with 3 columns. One of the columns, **QueryText** is of type mediumtext.
- In that column, we store data in

```
'<tag1><tag2>condition</tag2><tag3>price <> 10</tag3></tag1>' format.
```

After successful backup, if we open and check backup file (.SQL), INSERT statement contains text like

`INSERT INTO ABC VALUES(1, 100, '<tag1><tag2>condition</tag2><tag3>price &lt;&gt; 10</tag3></tag1>')`

So, here the issue <> is replaced with `&lt;&gt;`. When I restore same backup file in MySQL workbench, **<>** inserted into table as it is instead of <>.

Backup Tool - MySQL Administrator
Character set - latin1
Collation - latin1_swedish_ci
Please refer attachment for options set when taking backup.

Please suggest, how to stop HTML encoding while taking database backup.

Many Thanks.

I tried with NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES option. But, it doesn't work.